# I have two files need to take record count and checksum from this file and compare with other file

Tags: bash, shell, hadoop, hive, hdfs

I have two files one is sg_fx_cur_rates.csv need to take record count and checksum from this file and compare with other file sg_fx_cur_mapping_20170221.tok

**1st file**

```
head -10 sg_fx_cur_mapping_20170221.csv
```

---

```
UNIQUE IDENTIFIER AC CODE LONGNAME RISK FACTOR IDENTIFIER INSTRUMENT TYPE QUOTED CURRENCY BASE CURRENCY GLOBAL RATE LOCALE MXG_CURRENCY MXG_PIPSIZE MXG_LOCALE
SC.1000010374 FX_AED*USD_SPOT_GBL FX_AED*USD_SPOT_GBL  FX_SPOT AED USD 1 UK USD-AED  UK
SC.1000010375 FX_AMD*USD_SPOT_GBL FX_AMD*USD_SPOT_GBL  FX_SPOT AMD USD 1 UK
SC.1000010376 FX_ANG*USD_SPOT_GBL FX_ANG*USD_SPOT_GBL  FX_SPOT ANG USD 1 UK USD-ANG  UK
SC.1000010376 FX_ANG*USD_SPOT_GBL FX_ANG*USD_SPOT_GBL  FX_SPOT ANG USD 1 UK USD-ANG  SG
SC.1000010376 FX_ANG*USD_SPOT_GBL FX_ANG*USD_SPOT_GBL  FX_SPOT ANG USD 1 UK USD-ANG  US
SC.1000010377 FX_AOA*USD_SPOT_GBL FX_AOA*USD_SPOT_GBL  FX_SPOT AOA USD 1 UK USD-AOA  UK
SC.1000010377 FX_AOA*USD_SPOT_GBL FX_AOA*USD_SPOT_GBL  FX_SPOT AOA USD 1 UK USD-AOA  SG
SC.1000010378 FX_ARS*USD_SPOT_GBL FX_ARS*USD_SPOT_GBL  FX_SPOT ARS USD 1 UK USD-ARS  UK
SC.1000010380 FX_BBD*USD_SPOT_GBL FX_BBD*USD_SPOT_GBL  FX_SPOT BBD USD 1 UK USD-BBD  UK
```

**2nd file**

```
cat sg_fx_cur_mapping_20170221.tok
```

---

```
CHECKSUM|0b4e6c5935c39ae311dd477e216892d5
RECORDCOUNT|00000000681
```

Comment: Your question is too generic and quite badly formatted. Please improve it with better formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Since we don't have many clues (which checksum algorithm is being used?), here is one option :

```
> cat checker.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "CHECKSUM|"$(md5sum $1 | cut -d' ' -f1) > /tmp/$$
echo "RECORDCOUNT|"$(wc -l $1 | cut -d' ' -f1) >> /tmp/$$
if [ $(comm -1 -2 <(sort /tmp/$$) <(sort $2) | wc -l) -eq 2 ]
then
  echo "Files are equal"
else 
  echo "Files are different"
fi
rm /tmp/$$
return 0
```

And use it this way :

```
> checker.sh sg_fx_cur_mapping_20170221.csv sg_fx_cur_mapping_20170221.tok
```